# How to press only one key at time

Tags: javascript, onkeyup, onkeypress

I have this input text:

010 141 474 010 141 474

I want to press the above numbers in order that is presented, one by one. I use a flag to allow only one number at time, but it doesn't work correct. In the code that is depict I can press both numbers firt, but I want first 0, second 1, third 0 etc... And what about with duplicates numbers? I duplicate the code? Also I thought to check if a button is onkeyup but nothing. Any help? Thanks in advance. My code:

```
function keyPressed(event){
var code;
var isKeyRepeating = false;
if(window.event){ //IE
code = event.keyCode;
}
else{ //other browsers
code = event.which;
}

if (code == 48 || code == 96){ //both keycodes for the same number  
 document.onkeypress("0");
 isKeyRepeating = true;
}

if (code == 49 || code == 97){   
 document.onkeypress("1");
 isKeyRepeating = true;
}

else {
   event.preventDefault();
   isKeyRepeating  = false;
}
}
```

input field:

```
 <input style="border-style: inset" size="90" type="text" name="key" id="txtboxToFilter" onkeypress="javascript:keyPressed(event);"/>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: do you need a regular expression?

Comment: Replace the second+ occurrences of `if` with `else if`. Otherwise, the `else` block will almost always be executed.

Comment: Do you want the user to only input exactly these numbers? "010 141.." or not the same number twice in a row like "11". Can you explain again what you want and what you don't want.

Comment: Just like most people play the piano: use only one finger at a time :)

Comment: @ T.J Crowder this is nothing like exercise for me.

Comment: @  PiTheNumber Yes i want the user to enter only this numbers. In the following order, first 0, second 1, third again 0, fourth space, fifth 1, sixth 4, etc... Do you understand what I mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is most confusing. Typing one character at a time is completely trivial, unless you specifically want to prevent holding keys down. As such, I'm not sure what you even want.

If you want the user to only be able to type the characters in the correct order, this will work for you:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function keyPressed(event, input) {
    if (event.keyCode == 8) {
        // Allow backspace
        return true;
    }
    // Detect character code: event.which on Firefox, event.keyCode on IE
    var char = event.which ? event.which : event.keyCode;
    // Convert to string
    char = String.fromCharCode(char);
    var match = 'aBÁ 010 141 474 010 141 474';
    // Compare to character in match string and return result
    return (match.charAt(input.value.length) == char);
}
</script>

<input size="30" type="text" name="key" id="txtboxToFilter" onkeypress="return keyPressed(event, this);"/>
```

There is another answer which uses a similar function, but the critical difference is that it uses an `onkeydown` handler, which produces different results. One needs to understand that `onkeydown` deals with a single key pressed, while `onkeypress` deals with a single character typed. For example, if you type uppercase `A`, there are two `keydown` events: one for `shift`, another for `a`. There is however only one `keypress` event for `A`.

Even more critical is that one cannot expect all key codes to match with character codes when using `onkeydown`. For example, the key codes for numbers are different if typed from the numpad, and the key codes for special characters are completely unreliable. Using `onkeypress` however, the key codes will match with character codes, if the key represents a visible character.

Therefore, the deciding factor between using `onkeydown` or `onkeypress` is whether you wish to detect arbitrary key presses, or visible typed characters.

(The following was part of the original answer, while it turned out it was not what the OP wanted, I'm leaving it here for reference).

If you want the user to only be able to type number, this will do it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function keyPressed(event) {
    var char = event.which ? event.which : event.keyCode;
    char = String.fromCharCode(char);
    var regexp = /\d/;
    return regexp.test(char);
}
</script>

<input size="30" type="text" name="key" id="txtboxToFilter" onkeypress="return keyPressed(event);"/>
```

Comment: I wrote it and tested it on Firefox, and it worked fine. I suggest you check your error console, it probably gives some hint.

Comment: i tried again and works fine. if i change the numbers with letters  is it also works?

Comment: Yes, it will work with alphabet also, lowercase and uppercase, as well as special characters.

Comment: thank you for your details. It is help me a lot. I have a question. If I had more than one exercise like `var match = ['010 141 474 010 141 474' , '258 852 582 258 852 582' , ' etc..'];` it is more complicated to separate the code one for each exercise or combine in one? I have a dropdown menu which i can choose this exercise. I don't know if you understand me what i mean.

Comment: It should be quite easy to write a single function to handle all those possibilities, and duplicating the code would be just unnecessary. For example, if your dropdown is a `SELECT` element, you could easily use the `selectedIndex` attribute to choose the correct string in the match array.

Comment: I create a dropdown menu in a `xml file`. Show i don' t use a `SELECT` element. I use only an id e.g id='courses'. Is that a problem? xml it is look like: `<courses><br/> <course title="exercise1"><br/> <lesson>010 141 474 010 141 474</lesson><br/> </course> <br/> <course title="exercise2"> <br/>....etc <br/></courses>

Comment: can you give me an example how i can use the selectedIndex? Because i don't understand!

Comment: @f1delak1: Best place to look for examples and try them out would be W3Schools. [Their page on `selectedIndex` is here.](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_select_selectedindex.asp) Just remember that their specifications are not official, and may contain errors.

Answer (score 0):

If i have correctly understand you. You want some users to enter these numbers one-by-one? So you need to compare the entered key with the entire string and with the current string, build from prev. entered keys.

Comment: Yes something like this. Any suggestion how can do this?